# Bug calculating RSI or bug in MetaTrader 4?

Tags: c++, indicator, trading, metatrader4

I am creating a simple function in order to calculate Relative Strength Index ( **`RSI`** ). I am following the instructions from this website http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?st=stochastic+rsi&id=chart_school:technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi

For those sample values the code works perfectly. But for any forex data from MetaTrader 4, the expected value in MetaTrader is different.

This is the simplified code I am using:

```
double CalculateRSISimple(std::vector<ROWDATA>& aData, int nPos, int RSIPeriod)
{
    double dTotalGain = 0;
    double dTotalLoss = 0;
    double dRS = 0;
    double dRSI = 0;

    int nOffset = 0;
    int nPrevOffset = 0;
    for (int n = RSIPeriod-1; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        nOffset = nPos - n;
        nPrevOffset = nOffset - 1;

        double dDiff = aData[nOffset].dClose - aData[nPrevOffset].dClose;

        if (dDiff > 0)
        {
            dTotalGain += dDiff;
        }
        else
        {
            dTotalLoss -= dDiff;
        }
    }

    double dAveGain = dTotalGain / double(RSIPeriod);
    double dAveLoss = dTotalLoss / double(RSIPeriod);

    dRS = dAveGain / dAveLoss;
    dRSI = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1 + dRS));

    return dRSI;
}
```

It works perfectly with this sample data:

```
void TestRSI_1()
{
    // TEST

    std::vector<ROWDATA> vRowData;
    ROWDATA rowTemp;

    rowTemp.dClose = 44.338900;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 44.090200;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 44.149700;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 43.612400;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 44.327800;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 44.826400;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 45.095500;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 45.424500;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 45.843300;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 46.082600;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 45.893100;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 46.032800;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 45.614000;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 46.282000;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 46.282000;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);

    double dRSI = CalculateRSISimple(vRowData, 14, 14);

    if (fabs(dRSI - 70.5328) < 0.0001)
    {
        printf("... Test Passsed %f. Expected %f\n", dRSI, 70.5328);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("... Test Failed %f. Expected %f\n", dRSI, 70.5328);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use Forex data, the result is totally different than the expected by MetaTrader 4:

```
void TestRSI_3()
{
    // TEST

    std::vector<ROWDATA> vRowData;
    ROWDATA rowTemp;

    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11919; // 0:00
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11932;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11879;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11847;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11867;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11845;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11836;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11817;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11826;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);

    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11823;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11842;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11859;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11874;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11876;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);
    rowTemp.dClose = 1.11915;
    vRowData.push_back(rowTemp);

    double dRSI = CalculateRSISimple(vRowData, 14, 14);
    double dExpected = 58.4792;

    if (fabs(dRSI - dExpected) < 0.0001)
    {
        printf("... Test Passsed %f. Expected %f\n", dRSI, dExpected);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("... Test Failed %f. Expected %f\n", dRSI, dExpected);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
    Test Passsed 70.532789. Expected 70.532800
    Test Failed 49.264706. Expected 58.479200
```

I am wondering if MetaTrader4 calculates **`RSI`** in a different way?

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. I was forgetting to smooth out next elements in the series.